# Is there a way to sort and vertically merge dataframes in R if some have missing columns?

Tags: r

I am processing a group of .csv files with a lot of missing data and would like to get an idea of the availablity of two key variables "Upstream data" and "Downstream data". I used a for loop to go through each file, and for each file I added a column to indicate if upstream and downstream data are available using mapply and function.

```
>NOXcolorcode <- function(x,y){
>    if (is.na(x)){
>        if (is.na(y)) {
>            colorcode <- "Neither"
>        } else {
>            colorcode <- "Upstream Only"
>        } 
>    }else if (is.na(y)) {
>        colorcode <- "Downstream Only"
>    } else {
>        colorcode <- "Both"
>    }
>    return(colorcode)
>}

>Dataframe$NOXavailable <- mapply(NOXcolorcode,NOXup, NOXdown)
```

I would like to create a new table to record the data avaialibity  of each .csv file, based on an identifier named "VIN".

```
> summarytable <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 0))
> colnames(summarytable) <- c("VIN", "Upstream Only","Downstream Only","Both","Neither")
> summarytable
[1] VIN             Upstream Only   Downstream Only Both            Neither        
><0 rows>
```

My problem is, not all files have the 4 catagories. For example, table4 doesnt have the column "upstream only":

```
> table2
    Upstream Only        Downstream Only   Both         Neither        VIN
1   903                  5426              135270       60744          LFNADMKJ6LAN07529
> table4
    Downstream Only      Both              Neither      VIN
1   2690                 5425              22201        LFNADMJJXLAX43537
```

Is there a way I may vertically bind these tables? Ideally it would be in this kind format:

```
    Upstream Only        Downstream Only   Both         Neither        VIN
1   903                  5426              135270       60744          LFNADMKJ6LAN07529
2   NA                   2690              5425         22201          LFNADMJJXLAX43537
......
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What code did you use to get `table2`, `table4` ?

Comment: A table variable was generated in the for loop, using table() to count the frequnecy of each colorcode.  I then added the "VIN" column afterwards. I named there table1,table2,etc. only for the convience of this question.
'''
>table <- table(NOXavailable)
>table$VIN <- Truckid[1]
>table2 <- data.frame(table)
'''

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::bind_rows` which will take care of missing columns and assign it `NA`. If you have dataframes `table1`, `table2` ....`table5` try :

```
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(mget(paste0('table', 1:5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer (base R)**

Make `NOXavailable` a factor first, with fixed levels:

```
NOXavailable <- factor(NOXavailable, levels = c("Upstream Only", "Downstream Only", "Both", "Neither"))
table(NOXavailable)
```

Example with `NOXavailable <- sample(c("Downstream Only", "Both"), 100, r = T)`:

```
NOXavailable
  Upstream Only Downstream Only            Both         Neither 
              0              47              53               0
```

**Rationale**

Factors force `table` to display all levels of the factor, even when they are empty.

**Side-note**

It seems that you are calling `NOXcolorcode` for each entry of a column. Note that `is.na` is vectorized, so technically you can call it on the whole column at once. You may just want to write a function that runs `is.na` on the whole columns, and then assign the values that you want.